how to use yq with ansible to generate quotes around inserted items?
I am trying to add some items in an YAML file, calling yq (v4.43.1) from ansible (core 2.16.5).
It inserts the values correctly, but without the quotes that would make it a valid yaml file.
Now I am using ansible.builtin.replace to add quotes around my strings, but I am looking for a better solution.
Here is the playbook, it assumes that ansible and yq are already on the machine:
---
- name: Customize cluster.yaml
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    rook_tag: "v1.14.0"
    ceph_datapath:
      rpi4b-1: "sda3"
      rpi4b-2: "sda3"
      rpi4b-3: "sda3"
      rpi4b-4: "sda3"
      rpi4b-5: "sda3"
      rock3a: "nvme0n1p3"
      vim4: "nvme0n1"
      nanopct6: "mmcblk0p3"
      opi5p: "mmcblk0p3"
      rock5b: "mmcblk0p3"
  tasks:
    - name: Download cluster.yaml manifest from Internet
      ansible.builtin.get_url:
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rook/rook/{{ 'release-' + '.'.join(''.join(rook_tag.split('v')[1:]).split('.')[:2]) }}/deploy/examples/cluster.yaml"
        dest: ./cluster.yaml
        mode: '0664'

    - name: Set spec.storage.config.nodes
      ansible.builtin.shell: >
        /usr/local/bin/yq -i '.spec.storage.config.nodes += [{"name": "{{ item.key }}", "devices": [{"name": "{{ item.value }}"}]}]' cluster.yaml
      with_dict: "{{ ceph_datapath }}"
      register: command_output
      changed_when: command_output.rc == 0

The relevant section of the generated cluster.yaml file is:
config:
      nodes:
        - name: rpi4b-1
          devices:
            - name: sda3
        - name: rpi4b-2
          devices:
            - name: sda3
        - name: rpi4b-3
          devices:
            - name: sda3
        - name: rpi4b-4
          devices:
            - name: sda3
        - name: rpi4b-5
          devices:
            - name: sda3
        - name: rock3a
          devices:
            - name: nvme0n1p3
        - name: vim4
          devices:
            - name: nvme0n1
        - name: nanopct6
          devices:
            - name: mmcblk0p3
        - name: opi5p
          devices:
            - name: mmcblk0p3
        - name: rock5b
          devices:
            - name: mmcblk0p3

How can I add quotes around the names using yq?
Thank you!

Why would you want to add unrequired quotes?

because this is how they recommend in the file:
i  # nodes:     #   - name: "172.17.4.201"     #     devices: # specific devices to use for storage can be specified for each node     #       - name: "sdb"     #       - name: "nvme01" # multiple osds can be created on high performance device

It doesn't make sense. You're working w yaml. The values describes are strings. With or without quotes. What you're requesting isn't perse required.

It is recommended to not use shell nor replace in your case. There is also no need for yp. Have a look into in example Ansible replace/delete specific entrys ...

As stated in the comments, this is (in most cases) just aesthetics. But if you definitely want to restyle a YAML file, there's the YAML processor mikefarah/yq which you use to set a node's style to the single or double quoting style. First, traverse to the desired node(s), then apply, e.g., style = "double".
For example, to style all the values under .config.nodes[].name (which traverses to config, then to node, then iterates over all children, and finally descends to the name nodes):
yq '.config.nodes[].name style = "single"' file.yaml

config:
  nodes:
    - name: 'rpi4b-1'
      devices:
        - name: sda3
    - name: 'rpi4b-2'
      devices:
        - name: sda3
    - name: 'rpi4b-3'
      devices:
        - name: sda3
...

Alternatively, use the recursive descent operator .. to reach all items:
yq '.. style = "double"' file.yaml

config:
  nodes:
    - name: "rpi4b-1"
      devices:
        - name: "sda3"
    - name: "rpi4b-2"
      devices:
        - name: "sda3"
    - name: "rpi4b-3"
      devices:
        - name: "sda3"
...

